# Javascript lexical scoping

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain in plain language how this code works to give a result of 9?

what happens to the return of the inner function? I`m assuming that the enclosing function return is assigned to the variables  addTwo and addFive... where does the inner function get its argument (number)? I`m totally lost on this and the tutorial doesn`t explain it.

```
function makeAddFunction(amount) {
  function add(number) {
    return number + amount;
  }
  return add;
}

var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);
show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
```

**1**. `2` is assigned as `amount` and bound within the function scope. The inner `add` function has access to this, and so keeps it "cached".

So what is returned is essentially `function(number) { number + 2 };`

```
var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);
```

**2**. `5` is assigned the same way, and `function(number) { number + 5 };` is returned.

```
show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

**3.** `function( number ) {number+2}` is invoked and `1` is fed to the function, so `2+1` is returned which is `3`.

**4.** `function( number ){number+5}` is invoked and `5` is fed to the function, so `5+1` is returned which is `6`.

**5.** `6` and `3` are added, so we get `9`.

**6**. `9` is fed to the `show` function.

Comment: please explain one bit. when you say function (n ) {n + 2} is "invoked," is this because a reference to it was returned with "return add" and then stored in makeAddFunction(2), thereafter "invoked" by addtwo(1)? thanks for your help.

Comment: The `add` function is returned by the `makeAddFunction` and it remembers what `amount` you gave it so yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 2):

`makeAddFunction` returns function `add` that adds number to amount.

in line `var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);` you've created a function with `amount` 2.
If you call that function(`addTwo`) with some number, it return `2 + passed argument`

By this logic: `addTwo(1) = 2 + 1 = 3`,

`addFive(1) = 5 + 1 = 6`

`6 + 3 = 9`